# Are finite-dimensional representations of groups of type $\text{FP}_{\infty}$?

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a group (possibly infinite) and $k$ be a field.  A module $M$ over $k[G]$ is said to be of type $\text{FP}_{\infty}(k)$ if it has a projective resolution each of whose terms is finitely generated.  We say that $G$ itself is of type $\text{FP}_{\infty}(k)$ if the trivial $k[G]$-module $k$ is of type $\text{FP}_{\infty}(k)$.

Assume that $G$ is a group of type $\text{FP}_{\infty}(k)$ and that $M$ is a $k[G]$-module that is finite-dimensional over $k$ (in other words, $M$ is a finite-dimensional representation of $G$).  Must $M$ be of type $\text{FP}_{\infty}(k)$?  If not, are there stronger finiteness properties that we can put on $G$ to assure that this holds (for instance, having a compact $K(G,1)$)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Cleaned up answer (6/11/18) after comments of Andy Putman.**

The answer is yes.

Thm 2 of https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927870600796110 shows that if G is $FP_\infty$ over $k$, then $kG$ has a free resolution as a bimodule by finitely generated free bimodules in each dimension.

If you tensor this resolution with $M$ over $kG$ you get a free resolution of $M$ with the finiteness properties you want.  Tensoring with $M$ gives a resolution because its homology is $Tor^{kG}(M,kG)$.

It is easy to check that $(kG\otimes_k kG)\otimes_{kG} M\cong kG^{\dim M}$ as a left $kG$-module so that the free resolution is finitely generated in each degree.  The basis as a $kG$-module is the tensors $1\otimes 1\otimes b$ with $b$ running over a basis of $M$.

Comment: Exactness is preserved because the complex resulting of tensoring by $M$ computes $Tor^{kG}(M,kG)$.

Comment: @Mariano, that was the argument in [10]. Thanks!

Comment: Even after the edit, are you sure you linked to the paper you wanted to link to?  I believe that the result you refer to is Theorem 2 in https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927870600796110

Comment: @AndyPutman, I believe it was already known that bi-FP_n=FP_n for groups when Pride wrote this. I think I got confused the first time as to which paper proved it first. I'm not sure the publication dates of the communications in algebra papers reflect when they are written.

Comment: I don't know the history, so I can't say anything there.  But I have trouble locating the result you are talking about in Kobayashi-Otto's paper (indeed, it looks like they only talk about monoids, not groups).  Can you point out where it is?

Comment: I think it is not in that paper and I had meant to cite the paper of Kobayashi.

Comment: Kobayashi's paper cites Pride and attributes the result to him.

Comment: @AndyPutman,  I was working from memory 4 years ago and apparently my memory was not working.

Comment: I can't even remember what I was doing last week!  Probably the answer should be cleaned up so that a reader can find the original reference without wading through the comments.  Pride's proof is super-short (one could read and absorb it in 5-10 minutes).

Comment: @AndyPutman, thanks for recovering this history. I don't have access to Comm in Algebra and had a wrong impression which paper proved it.

Comment: Always happy to help!

Comment: @AndyPutman, I cleaned up the proof.